# Objective-C: Touch Draw Opacity

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-graphics

I am trying to make a drawing app that has a control on the opacity of the brush but when i tried to lower the opacity the result is like this. I used core graphics. (check the image).

[image]

How will i resolve this issue?

Here are some of my codes.

```
 -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event//upon touches
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    previousPoint1 = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    previousPoint2 = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    currentTouch = [touch locationInView:self.view];
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event//upon moving
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    previousPoint2 = previousPoint1;
    previousPoint1 = currentTouch;
    currentTouch = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    CGPoint mid1 = midPoint(previousPoint2, previousPoint1); 
    CGPoint mid2 = midPoint(currentTouch, previousPoint1);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(1024, 768));
    [imgDraw.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineCap(context,kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, slider.value);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, blendMode);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context,red, green, blue, 0.5);
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, mid1.x, mid1.y);
    CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(context, previousPoint1.x, previousPoint1.y, mid2.x, mid2.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    imgDraw.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    endingPoint=currentTouch;
}
```

Comment: It seems that your problem is a result of using a blend mode and the fact that you're repeated adding the separate paths to the image. You can either pursue the techniques described by NSResponder and myself, below, or alternatively you could turn off the blend mode, put the paths you're drawing on an otherwise transparent image that you present in front of your main image, and then you won't get that combinative effect of drawing individual paths that overlap with each other with that blend mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do your drawing in `-touchesMoved:withEvent:`.  In any event method, you should be updating what needs to be drawn, and then send -`setNeedsDisplay.`

As your code is written above, you're creating a path between each pair of locations you're getting from the event messages.

You should create a path in `-touchesBegan:withEvent:`, and add to it in `-touchesMoved:withEvent:`.

Comment: this is working well but i have buttons that will change the color of the brush and i can't integrate it using this way.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than updating the image for every `touchesMoved`, I'd suggest you don't resave the image every time, but rather add each `touchesMoved` to an array of data points. Then, in your drawing routine (as NSResponder suggests) pull up the original image and then redraw the whole path mapped out by your array of points. If you want to update your image at some point, do it on `touchesEnded`, but not for every `touchesMoved`.

Comment: No, he will need to update what he's drawing in -touchesMoved:, he just shouldn't be creating a path for each event as he is currently.

Comment: @NSResponder I thought that's what I said, not create a new path for each event, but rather collect the datapoints that the drawing method will use to create the path. I'm not understanding your comment.